# How to display income call page to receiver user when app is killed

Tags: android, ios, flutter, voip, callkit

I'm working on flutter voip app and i'm stuck ow how to display call page to receiver when app is killed 
Such as facebook or whatsapp do 
Is there  any way to achieve this with flutter ..if not how to achieve this natively

Answer (score 1):

You should use CallKit on IOS side for show native IOS call screen. When a voip notification came, You can show IOS call own screen. Also you should PushKit for get voip notifications.

Some plugins for show OS native call screens both android and iOS:

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_callkeep

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_callkit_voximplant